# Saving Amy and Rory in episode The Angels Take Manhattan

Tags: doctor-who

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can't the Doctor just land the TARDIS outside New York during 1938?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/24164/cant-the-doctor-just-land-the-tardis-outside-new-york-during-1938)

Spoilers:

> At the end of the episode *The Angels Take Manhattan* both Amy and Rory get 'zapped' back into the past by the Weeping Angels, leaving the Doctor alone.

But since the Doctor is still in the present and with his TARDIS (unlike in a previous episode with the Angels), why can't he travel to the past to the point Amy and Rory get ported to and save them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After defeating the angels using the paradox they created earlier in the episode, the Doctor says he can now no longer visit that part of time and space without destroying the whole planet. This means he cannot go back and save them.

Although they say they led a happy life together, so perhaps they do not need saving.

However, the show does contradict itself as river somehow (most likely with vortex manipulator) visited Amy in the past for her to publish the book. So why can't the doctor go with river's manipulator? No idea to be honest