# Why there is a tombstone for Rory in the cemetery of Queens 2012?

Tags: doctor-who

I've read the question [Can't the Doctor just land the TARDIS outside New York during 1938?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/24164/cant-the-doctor-just-land-the-tardis-outside-new-york-during-1938) and could not found a satisfying answer.

At the start of the S07E05 The Angels Take Manhattan, the Doctor, Rory and Amy were in NYC 2012. As the plot went on, it appeared there were baby Angels in NYC 2012 too. Rory got zap back to NYC 1938, which is a battery farm for the Angels. Rory witnessed his own death and his second death created a paradox so strong that undone the whole event and push them back to cemetery of Queens 2012.

At this point, all of them were safe. Except that there was a tombstone with the name of Rory on it. Then Rory saw it and coined his death once again. No one asked why there was a tombstone.

So why there is a tombstone for Rory in the cemetery of Queens 2012?

Comment: What is the question?!

Comment: Come on dude, it is on the title!

Comment: I've edit the question so it doesn;t answer itself.

Comment: Huh? The reason why there was a tombstone is because Rory died. He always dies.

Comment: His death was a fixed point. Only when Amy changed the past did her name also appear on the tombstone.

Answer (score 3):

Likely the reason is, because they knew of his death, and witnessed it, it became a sort of fixed moment in time. Thus even though it was escaped, time was conspiring to bring it to pass anyways.

Amy's choice had not been made yet, so her name did not appear until after she made the choice. As the Doctor explained, she was making a fixed point in time.

Now one could argue such sorts of things have happened before, but do to the highly unstable nature of things, it could cause time to not adapt to changes as easily as before.

Answer (score 0):

My theory is that the death of Rory were not undone and the tombstone reflected it. It is possible that with the time distortion and the time energy saved by the Angels, the paradox was overcame. The paradox could only provide sufficient energy to push back the second death of Rory and all of them were sent to the cemetery of Queens 2012, which was the time and place that the Tardis got bounced off after the first attempt to enter NYC 1938.

If we watch carefully, there was an Angel waiting overlooking the cemetery after the very instant that the Doctor, River, Amy and Rory got sent back to the cemetery Queens 2012. That angel was chasing after Rory to fulfill the death of Rory in 1938.